# Transaction has been declined - PayPal Payflow Pro Error

Tags: checkout, paypal, paypal-payflow-pro, magento2.3.7

#### Preconditions and environment

1. Magento 2.3.7-p4
2. Set Payment Method in Stores->Configuration->Sales->Payment Methods->Paypal Payflow Pro (Includes Express Checkout)

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Add product to cart
2. Go to checkout
3. Place an order using PayPal Payflow Pro. Enter proper CC details including the right CVV

#### Expected result

Successful order as CC details are ok

#### Actual result

1. Transaction has been declined. Display to the checkout page.

As far as I debug and know that
FILE: vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Service/Response/Validator/ResponseValidator.php
Code:
case Payflowpro::RESPONSE_CODE_FRAUDSERVICE_FILTER:

```
foreach ($this->validators as $validator) {

    if ($validator->validate($response, $transparentModel) === false) {
    
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Transaction has been declined'));
    }
}
```

Is throwing an error. I further debug and know that
File: vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Payflow/Service/Response/Validator/CVV2Match.php
`function isNotMatchCvv` is throwing an error but the customer enters the proper cvv.

I have checked the /var/log/payment.log for this transaction and check there is
PayPal PayflowPro response:
'CVV2MATCH' => 'Y' on the first Verified request But on the second Authorised request I am getting the result
'cvv2match' => 'N'.
And just after another request automatically calls for transaction Void.
My sales are down and now some customer are able to place an order, but the majority of the customer is getting an error
'**Transaction has been declined**' error.

#### Additional information

I have inserted the debug log and found it below
**While transaction success**

```
INFO (6): ResponseValidator::validate
 INFO (6): response result = 0
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- isMatchCvv
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): AVSResponse -- validate
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): IAVSResponse -- validate
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): SecureToken -- validate
 INFO (6): Transparent::authorize
 INFO (6): orderId = 1000047384
 INFO (6): ResponseValidator::validate
 INFO (6): response result = 0
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- isMatchCvv
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): AVSResponse -- validate
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): IAVSResponse -- validate`
```

While **Transaction has been declined**

```
 INFO (6): ResponseValidator::validate
 INFO (6): response result = 0
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- isMatchCvv
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): AVSResponse -- validate
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): IAVSResponse -- validate
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): SecureToken -- validate
 INFO (6): Transparent::authorize
 INFO (6): orderId = 1000047381
 INFO (6): ResponseValidator::validate
 INFO (6): response result = 0
 INFO (6): validator -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- validate
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- isMatchCvv
 INFO (6): CVV2Match -- isNotMatchCvv
 INFO (6): validation fail
 INFO (6): Transaction has been declined
```

[image: Paypal Transection Log]